# How can I get X, Y (and Z) coordinates of a shape (/Body) in Matlab/Python/JS?

Tags: javascript, python, matlab, generator, point

Hi I have a rectangle with rounded corners which I got through this:

```
figure
rectangle('position',[0 -1 10 2],'Curvature',[1])
axis equal
grid minor
```

But I need to get a list of x,y coordinates starting at the middle of the bottom line. it would also be useful to vary the number of coordinates I can get.

I'm trying to get draw a plate (basically a rectangle with rounded corners). If I don't use the function I did before how could I do it? essentially the x-coordinates would be the length of the plate, and the y-coordinates would be the height. I'm trying to get a number of x,y coordinates (which I can vary, say 200 coordinates to start with) starting at the middle bottom of the plate and then going anti-clockwise around the plate.

So to recap, starting at the middle bottom of the plate i need to get around 200 x,y coordinates anti-clockwise back to the middle bottom of the plate, but these coordinates have to follow a specific geometry (for now the shape of the plate, I think later I might change the shape.

[So i need a c**ontinuous path of points, equal distance from each other**, following **the perimeter of a shape/drawing/line/etc.**]

**This can be in any language - Matlab, Python, Java Script, C++, anything! :)**

I'm finding it really hard to explain, I hope this helps at least a little.

Regards,

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. But can you define a few things? What is equi-distance for your problem? For one dimension, you can have equi-distance on the curve and you can have equi-distance on the parameter. For higher dimensions, you can in some cases have equi-distance grids on a general "shape" but that becomes problematic very quick. If your "shape" is a hyper-surface, which can be considered as the image of a real-valued function 1 dimension lower, you may instead be interested in having a grid on the domain instead. What's your exact situation?

Comment: Ooo. Nothing that complicated, or at least not yet. Basically, let’s say you have a triangle. And you take a piece of string and stretch it around the perimeter. Starting at 1 corner, you record the xy cords.

Comment: For me. Equidistant is the same distance between points

Comment: High dimensions does sound fun, but this is just 2D fo now. Thanks :)

Comment: Huh, the edit didn’t seem to work. Ok: using the “string” , starting at one point, record the xy coord. Following a set distance along the string, say 2cm, move to the next point and record those cords. Do this until you make a full cycle around the perimeter. And record the x and y coordinations of all the points.

Comment: Is your shape manually inputted? Or is it a matrix containing coordinates outlining the shape? In the latter case, is it considered a polygon or do you have some sort of smooth interpolation requirements? In any case, it doesn't sound like there is a ready-made function. Do you have trouble implementing what you need yourself?

Comment: i seemed to get it to work, albeit i went way overkill. I now import an image, and find the pixels.

Comment: How is that an overkill?

Comment: Haha maybe for me.  It now it accounts for much greater inputs